# How to make a .each function output one HTML element match at a time instead of all matches

Tags: jquery

This jQuery .each function is returning the text for all of the matched elements instead of just one at a time.

**Clarification: The two text elements are nested inside each `$review`**

```
  var reviews = function(error, result, $) {
    $review = $(".ZWa.nAa");

  $review.each(function(index, a){
    $name = $('.d-s.ob.tv.Ub.ZUb.M5').text();
    $comment = $('.GKa.oAa').text();

    console.log("====" + $name + "====");
    console.log($comment);
  });
};
```

This is the current output:

```
====Tiffany NelsonKristin Ruiz====
I had never been to a chiropractor before and was not thrilled at the idea of going, but my back was killing me and I had no other choice. Dr Rosquist and his staff helped to ease my fear, kept me informed of everything they were doing and why, and were so helpful and friendly. After one visit they remembered who I was and even now when I go in only once a month or so they know me by name and ask me questions about my personal life and remember details from previous discussions. 

My back is doing much better and I feel like I can go back to my active lifestyle without being afraid of hurting my back again. They also helped me solve some other problems I had been having through some blood work tests and were helpful to explain why and why was going on. 

====Tiffany NelsonKristin Ruiz====
I had never been to a chiropractor before and was not thrilled at the idea of going, but my back was killing me and I had no other choice. Dr Rosquist and his staff helped to ease my fear, kept me informed of everything they were doing and why, and were so helpful and friendly. After one visit they remembered who I was and even now when I go in only once a month or so they know me by name and ask me questions about my personal life and remember details from previous discussions. 

My back is doing much better and I feel like I can go back to my active lifestyle without being afraid of hurting my back again. They also helped me solve some other problems I had been having through some blood work tests and were helpful to explain why and why was going on.
```

What I'm trying to return is:

```
====Tiffany Nelson====
I had never been to a chiropractor before and was not thrilled at the idea of going, but my back was killing me and I had no other choice. Dr Rosquist and his staff helped to ease my fear, kept me informed of everything they were doing and why, and were so helpful and friendly. After one visit they remembered who I was and even now when I go in only once a month or so they know me by name and ask me questions about my personal life and remember details from previous discussions. 

====Kristin Ruiz====
My back is doing much better and I feel like I can go back to my active lifestyle without being afraid of hurting my back again. They also helped me solve some other problems I had been having through some blood work tests and were helpful to explain why and why was going on.
```

**How do I go about getting this output?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your html I will assume that the 2 text elements are nested inside each `$review`

In that case you want to look within the specific instance of `$review` using `this` as the instance and `find()` to traverse it's descendants

```
  $review.each(function(index, a){
    $name =$(this).find('.d-s.ob.tv.Ub.ZUb.M5').text();
    $comment = $(this).find('.GKa.oAa').text();

    console.log("====" + $name + "====");
    console.log($comment);
  });
```

Please provide some html if this is not the current structure.

WHat you are doing is looking at the whole collection within the page for each class. Any getter method can only pull the first value it finds so will always return the same, regardless of how many elements are in the collection

Comment: Your assumptions are correct, and your answer worked like a charm. Thanks!! Just so I understand, why  are all of the instances being added in my code vs. yours?

Comment: see my last comment in answer, you are looking at every one of that class in the whole page and not isolating instances

Comment: That makes sense, so your answer is looking at the specific ``this`` instance as it goes through each element?

Comment: correct...then it will only `find()` the instances descendent from `this`

Comment: Perfect, thanks a ton! This is from a web crawler I am building in nodejs.